# Why CMD is not executed through neither the docker create nor docker start command?

Tags: docker

Consider the following `Dockerfile` being simple

```
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt update && apt install neofetch -y

CMD ["echo", "Hello From Docker to Ubuntu"]
```

According with some research the `RUN` instruction is executed only when the image is build through the `docker build` command and the `CMD` instruction is executed when the container is created and run from that custom image.

Therefore executing the `docker build` command as follows:

```
docker build -t my-ubuntu:001 .
```

Works as expected and executing the `docker run` command as follows:

```
docker run --name my-ubuntu-001-001 -it my-ubuntu:001
```

Works as expected, it mostly about the `Hello From Docker to Ubuntu` message that is displayed in the `tty`. Until here fine.

Now, exists the following equivalence:

- `docker run` = `docker create` + `docker start`

Therefore is possible create and run a container from the same custom image as follows:

```
docker create --name my-ubuntu-001-002 my-ubuntu:001
docker start my-ubuntu-001-002
```

The curious of this pair is that the `Hello From Docker to Ubuntu` message is **not** displayed in the `tty`. So why here is not shown the message? Is it the expected behavior or is missing something?

Comment: Does the container have stdout attached to your terminal? Should be `-a` flag. https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/start/

Comment: Correct, it works adding the `-a` to the `docker start` command. Consider to put it as an answer to mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the `-a` flag to attach the containers *stdout/stderr* to your terminal. Otherwise, the container will print the message, but it will not be shown in your terminal.

Fixed command:

```
docker start -a my-ubuntu-001-002
```

[Documentation](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/container/start/).

See also the `-i` flag to `docker start`, which is required if you want *stdin* to be attached.

Comment: Thanks, if my memory does not fail me, mostly is used the `-ai` option for the `docker start` command.

Comment: Just being curious, why the `docker run --name ubuntu-abc ubuntu date` command display the `date` output in the host's `tty`? I assumed it is printed within the running container, but because there is no a special option - as the `a` option - the host should be not able to see that output

Comment: @ManuelJordan In the case of `docker run`, the container is attached by default. You can pass the `-d` option to detach it. The `-i` and `-t` options only control stdin and whether a pseudo-tty is used.

Comment: Thanks, just in case, for a Linux container is mandatory use `itd` instead. The option `d` is viable for a Web Server such as `nginx`