# Trying to understand the relation of tty between the host and container when the docker run command is executed

Tags: docker

About Docker if is executed the following command

```
docker run --name ubuntu-it -it ubuntu
```

The container named `ubuntu-it`, based on the `ubuntu` image, is created, run, is offered a `tty` and finally remains running. It can be stopped with the `exit` command. Here the importance about the `it` option to have a shell available for human interaction. It to have available the features about the `STDIN` and `STDOUT/STDERR` streams **within** the current running container through the shell within the `tty`.

For experimental purposes, if is executed the following commands

```
docker run --name ubuntu-a ubuntu ls
docker run --name ubuntu-b ubuntu date
```

The containers named `ubuntu-a` and `ubuntu-b`, based on the `ubuntu` image, are created, run, are listed/displayed the execution of the `ls` and `date` commands and finally the containers are stopped.

The `ls` and `date` commands are executed *within* the running containers prior to be stopped.

**Question**

If the `it` option was **not** used for each `docker run` command.

- Why in the host's `tty` is possible see the listed/displayed data of the `ls` and `date` commands?

Comment: Both of these commands just print to stdout.  They don't read from their stdin and they don't care whether their stdout is a tty or not.

Comment: [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30137135/confused-about-docker-t-option-to-allocate-a-pseudo-tty#40026942) goes into a fair amount of detail on the tty mechanism within docker

Comment: @DavidMaze _Both of these commands just print to stdout_ - yes, but it is internally within the container. So: Why the host's tty is able to see the data? - I thought the `a` option should be mandatory. It is something similar than the following situation - https://stackoverflow.com/a/78054091/3665178

Comment: `docker run` (without a `-d` option) prints the process's stdout to its own stdout.  There's no particular reason you need a tty for most programs.  (Consider why you see output from plain `ls`, or a more involved `ls </dev/null 2>&1 | tee /dev/null` that's more forcibly disconnected from the terminal.)